# Is having a routing.yml file necessary?

Tags: 8, routes

I'm new to Drupal 8, and was curious why some modules have a *-routing.yml file, while others don't.

Why is this the case? Does this mean that modules lacking in a *-routing.yml file don't have any routing URLs?

Comment: There are other ways to provide routes beside routing file. The routing file is for static routes that you know you have. There is the  \Drupal\Core\Entity\Routing\EntityRouteProviderInterface for example, which allows you to provide routes programmatically - so based on the configuration the routes will change - hence cannot be placed in the routing file.

Answer (score 4):

`*.routing.yml` is used to define custom endpoints and their receiving controllers. It's the config version for `hook_menu` in D8. If the module does not introduce custom paths, then it will not need one.